# How can I set the patch with props.params in a react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the previous version react route v4. I could write

```
<Route path='OrdersView(&filters:filters)'
```

or

```
<Route path='OrderViewForm/classPartition=:classPartition&id=:id'
```

after use it like this:

```
this.props.location.query.filter
this.props.params.classPartition
```

How can I do this in version react router v4?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to use route with parameter

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Topic from '../topic'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/topics/:name" component={Topic} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And use it like this

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Topic(props) {
  return <h1>{props.match.params.name}</h1>
}
```

Source: 
https://jaketrent.com/post/access-route-params-react-router-v4/